# $\lfloor x^k \rfloor \equiv m \pmod{n}$ with $x$ irrational

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, congruences, irrational-numbers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $x>1$ be an irrational number, and $n$ a positive integer. Is it true that, for each integer $m$, there exists an integer $k$ such that
$$
\lfloor x^k \rfloor \equiv m \pmod{n}?
$$

Comment: One can use the usual closed form of the Fibonacci sequence and information about the period of its values modulo $10^k$ to conclude that there are not solutions to the similar equivalence $$\left\lfloor \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \phi^k \right\rfloor \equiv m \pmod n$$ for all $m$ for $n = 10^k$, $k > 2$. (Here, $\phi$ is the Golden Ratio, $\frac{1}{2}(1 + \sqrt{5})$.) Perhaps one can extract a counterexample for the original question by modifying this one.

Comment: (Oops, I overloaded $k$ here; the text after the display should real, "...for all $m$ for $n = 10^j$, $j > 2$.)

Comment: I noticed, don't worry :) Basically, the same idea of lulu's solution: The boring part seems to be the manual checking of remainders covered and not..

Comment: One can do that step pretty efficiently applying the recurrence relation itself modulo $n$ (it's arithmetic either way, but this approach spares ones from computing potentially high powers of $1 \pm \sqrt{2}$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit:  the first version incorrectly ignored the sign of the small term.  I have repaired that mistake.

In a similar spirit to the comment by Travis, it's good to look at expressions for which we know the fractional part.  For example:

$$A_n=\left(1+\sqrt2\right)^n+\left(1-\sqrt2\right)^n$$

these are always integral (indeed, The $A_n$ satisfy the Fibonacci-like recurrence $A_n=2A_{n-1}+A_{n-2}$) and the second term goes to $0$ rapidly.  Hence the integer part of the first term is either $A_n-1$. or $A_n$ according to the parity of $n$. We will use this to show that $\alpha=1+\sqrt2$ is a counterexample.

But work $mod(7)$, where $\sqrt2 = 3$.  We see that the $A_n$ are periodic.  In particular, they only take the values $2,5,6,0$ $mod(7)$. Checking cases we see that the only residue classes hit by the integer part of $\alpha^n$ are $0,1,2,5$ $mod(7)$.Thus we have a counterexample.

Comment: It also takes 6 sometimes. First time for $k=16$.

Comment: @wythagoras     $A_{16}$ = 1331714 (from the recurrence). Since $n$ is even, our guy $\alpha^{16}$ is just a hair less than that, so the integer part of $\alpha^{16}$ is 1331713 which is $5$ $mod(7)$.  Am I screwing it up?

Comment: @wythagoras To be clear, it doesn't hurt the main argument even if I've botched the $A_n$ vs $A_n -1$ part.  You still couldn't get $3$ as a residue.  But I think I have it right, no?  The residues are periodic with cycle  {$2,5,0,5,5,1$}.

Comment: I didn't work with enough precision, sorry to bother. The argument works, +1.

Comment: @wythagoras Oh, no worries.  I only have an old laptop with me and when I ran it just now I got all kinds of interesting values.  Forced to fall back on pencil and paper!

Comment: Thanks for the answer lulu. Having $x$ fixed, do you think it is possible to show that the number of $m$ for which there exists a solution $k$ is at least $cn$, for some $c>0$, independently on $n$?

Comment: @jordan Oh, I kind of doubt it.. Working with my $\alpha$ I'd search for primes $p$ for which $2$ is a quadratic residue and for which $2$ has a very low order $mod(p)$.  Mersenne primes, for example.  I expect they are all counterexamples.  Granted we don't know there are infinitely many of them...but you see the idea.

Comment: Oh, you are right: Hence, most probably there exists an irrational $x>1$ for which $\liminf_n s(n)/n=0$, where $s(n)$ is the number of $m \in \{0,1,..,n-1\}$ for which there exists a solution $k$.. Well, thank you :)